# BottomNav using React-Native-Paper

Tags: reactjs, react-native, frontend

I am learning react `native`, and using `react-native-paper`

I borrowed this dashboard screen from this example: https://github.com/venits/react-native-login-template.

```
import React from 'react'
import Background from '../components/Background'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Paragraph from '../components/Paragraph'
import Button from '../components/Button'

export default function Dashboard({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Background>
      <Logo />
      <Header>Let’s start</Header>
      <Paragraph>
        Your amazing app starts here. Open you favorite code editor and start
        editing this project.
      </Paragraph>
      <Button
        mode="outlined"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ name: 'StartScreen' }],
          })
        }
      >
        Logout
      </Button>
    </Background>
  )
}
```

On it's own, this renders fine. Sorry the image is so big.

[image]

I am trying to add a bottom navigation bar to this screen. I borrowed this component from this `react-native-paper` example: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/components/BottomNavigation.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper';


const MusicRoute = () => <Text>Music</Text>;

const AlbumsRoute = () => <Text>Albums</Text>;

const RecentsRoute = () => <Text>Recents</Text>;

const NotificationsRoute = () => <Text>Notifications</Text>;

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
    const [routes] = React.useState([
        { key: 'music', title: 'Favorites', focusedIcon: 'heart', unfocusedIcon: 'heart-outline' },
        { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', focusedIcon: 'album' },
        { key: 'recents', title: 'Recents', focusedIcon: 'history' },
        { key: 'notifications', title: 'Notifications', focusedIcon: 'bell', unfocusedIcon: 'bell-outline' },
    ]);

    const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
        music: MusicRoute,
        albums: AlbumsRoute,
        recents: RecentsRoute,
        notifications: NotificationsRoute,
    });

    return (
        <BottomNavigation
            navigationState={{ index, routes }}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            renderScene={renderScene}
        />
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I tried updating my `dashboard.js` file to use this bottomNav in the following way.

```
import React from 'react'
import Background from '../components/Background'
import Logo from '../components/Logo'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Paragraph from '../components/Paragraph'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import MyComponent from '../components/BottomNavigation'

export default function Dashboard({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <Background>
      <Logo />
      <Header>Let’s start</Header>
      <Paragraph>
        Your amazing app starts here. Open you favorite code editor and start
        editing this project.
      </Paragraph>
      <Button
        mode="outlined"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.reset({
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ name: 'StartScreen' }],
          })
        }
      >
        Logout
      </Button>
      <MyComponent/>
    </Background>
  )
}
```

However, the app doesn't render in the way I would expect. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't see it is because it gets 0-width due to the `alignItems: 'center'` style applied to the `Background` element ([see here](https://github.com/venits/react-native-login-template/blob/master/src/components/Background.js#L31)). You need to give some style to your `BottomNavigation` in order to avoid that:

```ts
<BottomNavigation
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  onIndexChange={setIndex}
  renderScene={renderScene}
  style={{ width: '100%' }}
/>
```

Or using the `StyleSheet` utility:

```ts
<BottomNavigation
  navigationState={{ index, routes }}
  onIndexChange={setIndex}
  renderScene={renderScene}
  style={styles.navigation}
/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navigation: {
    width: '100%',
    // Add any other style here
  },
})
```

Keep in mind that your `BottomNavigation` element contains both the bottom bar, AND the displayed page. You will need to think about its usage in your final app.

I would suggest you this docs as further reading to integrate the bottom navigation using React Native Paper in your app: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator